# Cant start onlyoffice-document server without docker?

Tags: node.js, onlyoffice

I had installed onlyoffice document server on my ubuntu 14.04 machine but after I restarted the server all the applications of onlyoffice shutdown and I am not able to restart them. It currently shows 502 gateway error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason - problem with `supervisor`, but that problem was on Ubuntu 16.04 with `systemd`
It was solved via

```
# Make sure Supervisor comes up after a reboot.
sudo systemctl enable supervisor

# Bring Supervisor up right now.
sudo systemctl start supervisor
```

See https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DocumentServer/issues/77

Comment: Used following commands for ubuntu 14.04 - 
sudo update-rc.d supervisor defaults, 
sudo service supervisor start